# MySQL query Error with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to do this:

```
<?php 
$query ="SELECT * FROM servers, bans WHERE servers.ServerID = bans.ServerID ORDER BY BanID DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){     
?>
```

but I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Access\repository\HT2\WH\www.voltzgaming.com\public_html\GBans\index.php on line 139
```

Comment: Print `mysql_error()` to see the error in your SQL.

Comment: If you put your error message into the search box, how many questions do you see with the exact same error?

Comment: Are you _connected_ to your database? You need to do error checking, _always_ with the `mysql_*()` extension.

Comment: meanwhile, no new code should be written with `mysql_*()`. The extension has been deprecated, and new code should be built with either the MySQLi or PDO extensions.

Comment: Bored with this. Why does nobody check for error with their MySQL code?

Comment: @MikeW I'm more puzzled by the fact that apparent newbies are still using the MySQL extension. Where are they getting this advice?

Comment: @MikeW [because of garbage like this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_fetch_array.asp) all over the interwebs.

Comment: @Phil Any of hundreds of out-of-date tutorials on the web, I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mysql_query($query)` is returning a `false` because you have a syntax error in the SQL.

Use `mysql_error()` after the query is run to see what the problem is.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm semi-new to this?

Comment: Hmm, I just added 'mysql_error()' but I'm not getting anything extra?

Comment: are you connecting to the database before attempting to run this query?

Comment: @user3010325 You can't just _add_ mysql_error(). It's a function which returns a string.  `if (!$result) echo mysql_error();`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: tmp in C:\xampp\htdocs\Access\repository\HT2\WH\www.voltzgaming.com\public_html\GBans\index.php on line 185 is what I'm getting after echoing errors ?

Comment: After seeing that, we cannot help you. You'll need to contact the people who wrote the software you're attempting to alter. Sorry dude.

Comment: @user3010325 That's a separate unrelated error about a variable `$tmp` -  not part of the code you've posted.

Comment: Oh okay, well this is annoying :3 Thanks guys <3